# Editing waveform audio input before it reaches a application

Tags: windows, winapi, hook, waveform, dll-injection

I am working on a voice changer that is supposed to manipulate the input buffer of a waveform-audio input device before the buffer is returned to a application.

The waveInOpen()-function gives 4 options to be notified when the buffer provided by waveInAddBuffer() has been filled.

The options are CALLBACK_EVENT, CALLBACK_FUNCTION, CALLBACK_THREAD, CALLBACK_WINDOW.

I have tried several things to to get my waveform manipulation to work but haven't found a reliable and clean solution yet.

What worked so far was intercepting waveInAddBuffer()-calls with Detours. I am saving all WAVEHDR-pointer used by waveInAddBuffer() and each time the function is called I delay the program for a few miliseconds and search for waveform-buffers that have been filled during the delay.
This isn't reliable though because the buffer size differs for each application and therefore there isn't a delay-time that works for every application.

I would be really thankful for new ideas!

edit: 
Heres the other stuff I have tried:

Most applications set multiple flags when calling waveInOpen() that actually exclude each other. So you can never be sure what callback method actually is used. (e.g.: the flags CALLBACK_EVENT | CALLBACK_FUNCTION | CALLBACK_WINDOW are all set.)

When the CALLBACK_WINDOW flag is set, I have used the SetWindowLongPtr() function to create a subclass window that received MM_WIM_DATA messages before the window of the application. Unfortunately this didn't work, my subclass window never gets called.

I have created a custom-callback function that I replace with the callback function of the application when the CALLBACK_FUNCTION flag is set.
This didn't work because my function never gets called. I guess this is because my function is defined in a DLL, outside of the address space of the application.

There were several other things I have tried that didn't work because I made attempts that never could have worked because I didn't know enough about injection and hooks. I have learned quite a lot and I cant really summarize everything I have tried, because it's not helping the cause.

Comment: *"I have tried several things to to get my waveform manipulation to work"* - Well, then, show those attempts and describe the specific issues you ran into. [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) serves as a check list.

Comment: I am working on this nonstop for 3 days it would take me forever to describe everything. The only thing that worked is described in my question. But alright I will add my other atempts.